# Make Mountain Lion always prompt before printing

Tags: macos, printing, osx-mountain-lion

In Mountain Lion, if I select files in Finder and go to Print, they immediately print. I'm not prompted to choose a printer, adjust settings, etc.

I don't like this feature. Is there a setting I can change to ensure that I'm always prompted before printing?

Comment: Does CMD+P bring up the dialog?

Comment: @techie007 No. Cmd+P immediately opens the selected document in Preview, prints it to the default printer, then closes the document in Preview.

Comment: Good question. I guess that's why they didn't map `Cmd-P` to print directly from the Finder because accidentally pressing it would cause chaos.

Answer (score 1):

how about pausing and unpausing printers? I have 20+ printers configured, that are spread across the world (literally), and usually I have all printer queues paused because of this, so I can see in which queue something lands when I print. Then up comes a dialog "The printer is paused - do you want to unpause it?"

Comment: Good point, but there has to be a more direct solution...